# Can a summation of logs be simplified?

Tags: summation

Probably a very easy question, but I can't find a simplification for the following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\log(a_i)$$

Can this summation be simplified?

Comment: Do you consider $\log(a_1 \cdots a_n)$ (or $\log(a_1\cdots a_n)+2\pi i k_n$ for some integer $k_n$, if $a_k$'s are allowed to be complex-valued) as simplified?

Comment: not really, I am doing an max likelihood estimator problem where the next step is to differentiate the above multiplied by x and wrt x. I am then left with the above.

Comment: Honestly, with no extra information supplied, I can hardly believe that your expression can be simplified further.

Comment: Thanks I will use as is in the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint.

$$\log(a) + \log(b) = \log(ab)$$

Now, extend it to $a_n$ elements.

Comment: Remember that it holds as long as all the $a_n$ are greater than zero.

Comment: do you mean $\log(a_1 \cdots a_n)$

Comment: @tony1kenobi Suppose your sum ends at $n = 3$ then you have

$$\log(a_1) + \log(a_2) + \log(a_3)$$

Which you may manipulate as

$$\log(a_1\cdot a_2) + \log(a_3)$$

hence

$$\log(a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3)$$

Eventually you'll end up in obtaining the logarithm of a productory.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \phantom{\Big(}\log(a_1) + \log(a_2) + \log(a_3) + \log(a_4) + \log(a_5) +\log(a_6) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big(\log(a_1)+\log(a_2)\Big) + \log(a_3) + \log(a_4) + \log(a_5) +\log(a_6) \\
= {} & \Big(\log(a_1a_2)\Big) + \log(a_3) + \log(a_4) + \log(a_5) +\log(a_6) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big(\log(a_1a_2) + \log(a_3)\Big) + \log(a_4) + \log(a_5) +\log(a_6) \\
= {} & \Big( \log(a_1a_2a_3) \Big) + \log(a_4) + \log(a_5) +\log(a_6) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big( \log(a_1a_2a_3) + \log(a_4)\Big) + \log(a_5) +\log(a_6) \\
= {} & \Big( \log(a_1a_2a_3a_4)\Big) + \log(a_5) +\log(a_6) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big( \log(a_1a_2a_3a_4) + \log(a_5)\Big) +\log(a_6) \\
= {} & \Big( \log(a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5)\Big) +\log(a_6) \\[10pt]
= {} & \cdots \cdots
\end{align}

You can make the above argument into a proof by mathematical induction if you want to.